# What do the multiplied defense stats mean?

Tags: achievements, ingress

[image: Defense Stats]

The stats "Max Time Portal Held", "Max Time Link Maintained", and "Max Time Field Held" are pretty easy to understand but "Max Link Length x Days" and "Largest Field MUs x Days" are a little confusing.

How are they calculated?

If I had a link of 100 km up for 20 days, would the "Max Link Length x Days" be calculated as 2000 km-days?

If it's so does it mean that I had a 2817/90=31,3 km long link up for 90 days? or was this value calculated from another longer link that I had up for a shorter time?

(Why don't they show the values for "Max Length Link Maintained" and "Max MU Field Held"? I understand that when expressed like this, these captions look like the same thing as "Longest Link Ever Created" and "Largest Control Field" but I guess you see my point here. 2817 km-days doesn't tell me how it was calculated.)

Comment: I'm not even sure what's the use of those xDays stats..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is my understanding that `Max Link Length x Days` and `Largest Field MUs x Days` treats the `x` as multiplication and shows the largest total value of that equation that you've acquired rather than only showing you the value from your largest link or field. So, if you had a small field for several days as opposed to a large field for a single day, the smaller field may be the value represented there.

Using my own stats as an example:

> #### Building
>
> - Longest Link Ever Created: **8 km**
> - Largest Control Field: **368 MUs**
>
> #### Defense
>
> - Max Time Link Maintained: **12 days**
> - Max Link Length x Days: **55 km-days**
> - Max Time Field Held: **1 days**
> - Largest Field MUs x Days: **32 MU-days**

Here, my maximum time maintaining a link is 12 days and my longest link ever made is 8 km. I know for a fact that the 8 km link didn't last more than 3 days, so the 55 km-days value does not correlate. My maximum time maintaining a field is 1 day and my largest field is 368 MUs. That field only lasted about 2 hours which is close to the value of 32 MU-days (more like 30), but I'm also sure that the value was 32 MU-days prior to creating my largest field. (I also suspect Niantic doesn't calculate partial days, but I have no evidence to back that assumption in this particular case.)

As for the aside in your question asking why they don't give you a statistic specifically about your performance with your longest link or largest field, I imagine it'd be out of the scope of the statistics. Every statistic is always either *increasing* or *remaining static*. A statistic that showed your performance with your longest link or largest field could potentially decrease as you create longer links and larger fields with more risk of being broken quicker. The statistics seem to cater to the "these numbers are **my** numbers and I will make them big" appeal.